# GNU Radio circular buffer manipulation

Tags: gnuradio, circular-buffer, gnuradio-companion

I encountered the following error

```
gr::log :WARN: tpb_thread_body - asynchronous message buffer overflowing, dropping message
```

Out of serendipity, I ran into this GNU Radio presentation on
[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDz9Ove0Dgc).

The presenter mentioned an OOT block he called "buffer" that is capable of eliminating the "buffer overflowing" error. Apparently, this block plays with different sample rates and the so-called "circular buffers". I haven't worked with circular buffers myself. Any ideas on circular buffers or any hints on how to build this buffer block are welcome.

[image: Flowgraph]

## EDIT

Below is the flowgraph that generates the error. As it was suggested in the comments, the culprits could be the message processing blocks (red-circled) namely generateCADU (for generating standard CCSDS frames) and processCADU (for extracting CADUs from a data stream). 
[image: flowgraph]
The implementation file of the generateCADU block is given below

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include <gnuradio/io_signature.h>
#include "generateCADU_impl.h"
#include "fec/ReedSolomon/ReedSolomon.h"
#include "fec/Scrambler/Scrambler.h"

namespace gr {
  namespace ccsds {

generateCADU::sptr
generateCADU::make(int frameLength,std::string sync, int scramble, int rs, int intDepth)
{
  return gnuradio::get_initial_sptr
    (new generateCADU_impl(frameLength, sync, scramble, rs, intDepth));
}

/*
 * The private constructor
 */
generateCADU_impl::generateCADU_impl(int frameLength,std::string sync, int scramble, int rs, int intDepth)
  : gr::sync_block("generateCADU",
          gr::io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(unsigned char)),
           gr::io_signature::make(0, 0, 0)),
d_frameLength(frameLength),d_scramble(scramble == 1),d_rs(rs >= 1), d_basis(rs >= 2), d_intDepth(intDepth)

{
  set_output_multiple(d_frameLength);
  //Registering output port
  message_port_register_out(pmt::mp("out"));
  d_sync = parse_string(sync);
}

/*
 * Our virtual destructor.
 */
generateCADU_impl::~generateCADU_impl()
{
}

unsigned char
generateCADU_impl::parse_hex(char c)
{
  if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') return c - '0';
  if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') return c - 'A' + 10;
  if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') return c - 'a' + 10;
  std::abort();
}

std::vector<unsigned char>
generateCADU_impl::parse_string(const std::string & s)
{
  if (s.size() % 2 != 0) std::abort();
  std::vector<unsigned char> result(s.size() / 2);

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != s.size() / 2; ++i)
    result[i] = 16 * parse_hex(s[2 * i]) + parse_hex(s[2 * i + 1]);

  return result;
}
int
generateCADU_impl::work(int noutput_items,
    gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
    gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
{
  const unsigned char *in = (const unsigned char *) input_items[0];

  //Reed-Solomon and Scrambler objects
  ReedSolomon RS(16,d_intDepth,d_basis);// False = conventional, True = dual-basis
  Scrambler S;

  //Buffers
  unsigned char *frameBuffer1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(d_frameLength*sizeof(unsigned char));
  std::vector<unsigned char> frameBuffer2;

  //The work function engine
  for(int i = 0; (i + d_frameLength) < noutput_items; i += d_frameLength)
{
  //Copying data from input stream
  memcpy(frameBuffer1,in + i + d_frameLength,d_frameLength);

  //Copying frame into std::vector buffer
  frameBuffer2.insert(frameBuffer2.begin(),frameBuffer1, frameBuffer1 + d_frameLength);

  //Optional scrambling and Reed-Solomon
  if (d_rs) RS.Encode_RS(frameBuffer2);
  if (d_scramble) S.Scramble(frameBuffer2);

  //Insert sync word
  frameBuffer2.insert(frameBuffer2.begin(), d_sync.begin(), d_sync.end());

  //Transmitting PDU
  pmt::pmt_t pdu(pmt::cons(pmt::PMT_NIL,pmt::make_blob(frameBuffer2.data(),frameBuffer2.size())));
  message_port_pub(pmt::mp("out"), pdu);

  //Clear buffer
  frameBuffer2.clear();
}

  // Tell runtime system how many output items we produced.
  return noutput_items;
}

} /* namespace ccsds */
} /* namespace gr */
```

And here is the processCADU block. This block uses tags generated by the synchronizeCADU (which is simply a wrapper for the correlate_access_tag block) to extract CADUs

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include <gnuradio/io_signature.h>
#include "processCADU_impl.h"
#include "fec/ReedSolomon/ReedSolomon.h"
#include "fec/Scrambler/Scrambler.h"

namespace gr {
   namespace ccsds {

processCADU::sptr
processCADU::make(int frameLength, int scramble, int rs, int intDepth, std::string tagName)
{
  return gnuradio::get_initial_sptr
    (new processCADU_impl(frameLength, scramble, rs, intDepth, tagName));
}

/*
 * The private constructor
 */
processCADU_impl::processCADU_impl(int frameLength, int scramble, int rs, int intDepth, std::string tagName)
  : gr::sync_block("processCADU",
           gr::io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(unsigned char)),
           gr::io_signature::make(0, 0, 0)),
d_frameLength(frameLength),d_scramble(scramble == 1),d_rs(rs >= 1), d_basis(rs >= 2), d_intDepth(intDepth)
{
  //Multiple input
  set_output_multiple(d_frameLength * 8);

  //Registering output port
  message_port_register_out(pmt::mp("out"));

  if (d_rs) d_frameLength += 32 * d_intDepth;
  //SEtting tag name
  key = pmt::mp(tagName);
}

/*
 * Our virtual destructor.
 */
processCADU_impl::~processCADU_impl()
{
  delete d_pack;
}

int
processCADU_impl::work(int noutput_items,
           gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
           gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
{
  const unsigned char *in = (const unsigned char *) input_items[0];
  unsigned char *out = (unsigned char *) output_items[0];

  void *msg_data = NULL;
  unsigned char frame_data[d_frameLength];
  unsigned char frame_len = 0;
  std::vector<unsigned char> frameBuffer;

  //Reed-Solomon and Scrambler objects
  ReedSolomon RS(16,d_intDepth,d_basis);// False = conventional, True = dual-basis
  std::vector<int> errors;//errors.push_back(0);
  Scrambler S;

  d_tags.clear();
  d_pack = new blocks::kernel::pack_k_bits(8);

  this->get_tags_in_window(d_tags, 0, 0, noutput_items,key);
  for(d_tags_itr = d_tags.begin(); d_tags_itr != d_tags.end(); d_tags_itr++) {
// Check that we have enough data for a full frame
if ((d_tags_itr->offset - this->nitems_read(0)) > (noutput_items - (d_frameLength) * 8))
  {
    return (d_tags_itr->offset - this->nitems_read(0) - 1);
  }
//Pack bits into bytes
d_pack->pack(frame_data, &in[d_tags_itr->offset - this->nitems_read(0)], d_frameLength);

//Copying frame into std::vector buffer
frameBuffer.insert(frameBuffer.begin(),frame_data, frame_data + d_frameLength);

//Optional scrambling and Reed-Solomon
if (d_scramble) S.Scramble(frameBuffer);
//if (d_rs) RS.Decode_RS(frameBuffer,errors);
//If there is Reed-Solomon decoding

if(d_rs)
  {
    RS.Decode_RS(frameBuffer,errors);
    if (RS.Success(errors)) // Success
      {
    //std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
    pmt::pmt_t pdu(pmt::cons(pmt::PMT_NIL,pmt::make_blob(frameBuffer.data(),frameBuffer.size())));
        message_port_pub(pmt::mp("out"), pdu);
    /*for(int i=0; i < errors.size(); i++)
      {

        //std::cout << "Number of Errors : " << errors.at(i) << std::endl << std::endl;
        }*/
      }
    else // Failure
      {
    std::cout << "RS failure" << std::endl;
      }
  }
  else{
  pmt::pmt_t pdu(pmt::cons(pmt::PMT_NIL,pmt::make_blob(frameBuffer.data(),frameBuffer.size())));
  message_port_pub(pmt::mp("out"), pdu);
  }

//Clear buffers
frameBuffer.clear();
errors.clear();
  }

  // Tell runtime system how many output items we produced.
  return noutput_items;
}

} /* namespace ccsds */
} /* namespace gr */
```

Regards,
M

Comment: You're misinterpreting something. The output buffer of **every** block is a circular buffer. And: that block can't have anything to do with your problem, as it doesn't deal with messages, and your error has to do with message passing. So, wrong track.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You are absolutely right. But, my flowgraph has a number of blocks before the "message processing" block. The flowgraph also hangs after I have transferred around 0.5 gigabytes of data. So in addition to the errors caused by the message passing block, I will also like suggestions on how to implement the buffer block.

Comment: you don't need that. I promise. You can just increase the minimum output buffer size of the upstream block, and let GNU Radio handle the buffer. It would do the same, only smarter.

Comment: and if your flowgraph hangs after 0.5 GB, you have a bug, not something that needs buffering! Or, you have something like a storage bottleneck, in which you need buffering, but in the operating system's file system handling. Anyway, not knowing your application, I'd argue that you're asking about something you don't show here – I'm afraid that qualifies as "too unclear" to be answered :(

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fair enough. I have added the full flowgraph and the implementation files of the blocks that process messages.

Comment: Hm, is there a specific reasons your blocks generate PDUs if all you do is immediately convert them to tagged stream?

Comment: The problem really is that something after a "PDU to tagged stream" block is slower at consuming samples (or stops doing it) than what you push  in on average, leading to the message input buffer of "PDU to tagged stream" overflowing. That happens because messages have no backpressure (unlike the rest of GNU Radio). Enlarging a buffer here will likely only *postpone* the problem, not solve it; this probably boils down to you having to quantify the performance of blocks and figuring out how to improve that (also, you should probably really just let generateCADU produce a length-tagged stream).

Comment: @MarcusMüller generateCADU generates PDUs because it does some operations i.e. Reed-Solomon, Additive Scrambling (and in the near future, LDPC and Turbo codes), which operate on blocks of data rather than individual samples. Are you saying that it is possible to rewrite the block in such a way that it produces a stream of bytes rather than PDUs? I thought about trying that though im not sure about how to specify the number of input/output samples. I cant use a "sync" or "interpolator" in this case

Comment: that's what the "tagged stream block" paradigma is for! read about that in the *GNU Radio doxygen documentation*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarcusMüller suggestion, using the tagged_stream paradigma as opposed to PDUs solved the problem. I was able to transmit 47 terabytes of data without any problems. Below is the code for the newly implemented block.

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include <gnuradio/io_signature.h>
#include "genCADU_impl.h"


namespace gr {
  namespace ccsds {

genCADU::sptr
genCADU::make(int frameLength,std::string sync, int scramble, int rs, int intDepth, std::string len_tag_key)
{
  return gnuradio::get_initial_sptr
    (new genCADU_impl(frameLength, sync, scramble, rs, intDepth, len_tag_key));
}

/*
 * The private constructor
 */
genCADU_impl::genCADU_impl(int frameLength,std::string sync, int scramble, int rs, int intDepth, std::string len_tag_key)
  : gr::tagged_stream_block("genCADU",
          gr::io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(unsigned char)),
          gr::io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(unsigned char)),len_tag_key),
    d_frameLength(frameLength),d_scramble(scramble == 1),d_rs(rs >= 1), d_basis(rs >= 2), d_intDepth(intDepth)
{
    //Synchronization pattern
    d_sync = parse_string(sync);

    //Reed-Solomon and Scrambler objects
RS = new ReedSolomon(16,d_intDepth,d_basis);// False = conventional, True = dual-basis
    S = new Scrambler();
}

/*
 * Our virtual destructor.
 */
genCADU_impl::~genCADU_impl()
{
  delete RS;
  delete S;
}

int
genCADU_impl::calculate_output_stream_length(const gr_vector_int &ninput_items)
{
  int noutput_items = (d_rs) ? d_frameLength + 32*d_intDepth + d_sync.size() : d_frameLength + d_sync.size();
  return noutput_items ;
}

unsigned char
genCADU_impl::parse_hex(char c)
{
  if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') return c - '0';
  if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') return c - 'A' + 10;
  if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') return c - 'a' + 10;
  std::abort();
}

std::vector<unsigned char>
genCADU_impl::parse_string(const std::string & s)
{
  if (s.size() % 2 != 0) std::abort();
  std::vector<unsigned char> result(s.size() / 2);

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != s.size() / 2; ++i)
    result[i] = 16 * parse_hex(s[2 * i]) + parse_hex(s[2 * i + 1]);

  return result;
}

int
genCADU_impl::work (int noutput_items,
                   gr_vector_int &ninput_items,
                   gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
                   gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
{
  const unsigned char *in = (const unsigned char *) input_items[0];
  unsigned char *out = (unsigned char *) output_items[0];

  int total_len;

  //Copy pdu from circular buffer to local buffer
  buffer.insert(buffer.end(), in, in +  d_frameLength);

  //Optional scrambling and Reed-Solomon. TO DO: Turbo and LDPC
  if (d_rs) RS->Encode_RS(buffer);
  if (d_scramble) S->Scramble(buffer);

  //Insert sync word
  buffer.insert(buffer.begin(), d_sync.begin(), d_sync.end());

  //Copy from local buffer to circular buffer
  std::copy(buffer.begin(),buffer.end(),out);

  //Clear the local buffer
  total_len = buffer.size();
  buffer.clear();

  // Tell runtime system how many output items we produced.
  return total_len;
}

} /* namespace ccsds */
} /* namespace gr */
```

Regards,

M.